# Given two integers m and n, loop repeatedly through an array of m and remove each nth element. Return the last element left

Tags: python

Given two integers `m` and `n`, loop repeatedly through an array of `m` and remove each nth element. 
Return the last element left.

(If `m = 7` and `n = 4`, then begin with the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and remove, in order, `[4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 7]` and return `3`)

Shouldn't this return `2` and not `3`?

Comment: I believe you're right that this should reurn 2 and not 3. Based on the "remove, in order", it should go `4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 3` and finally leaving `2`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It should return 2.

Sample code

```
a=[i for i in range(1,8)]
n=4
k=n
m=7
while len(a)!=0:
    print(a)
    print("poped ",a.pop((n-1)%m))
    n = (n-1)%m+ k
    m = m-1
    print()
```

and the output,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
poped  4

[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
poped  1

[2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
poped  6

[2, 3, 5, 7]
poped  5

[2, 3, 7]
poped  7

[2, 3]
poped  3

[2]
poped  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should return 2, if the algorithm is meant to return the last element in the list

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 . 5 6 7 (4)
. 2 3 5 6 7 (1)
2 3 5 . 7 (6)
2 3 . 7 (5)
2 3 . (7)
2 . (3)
```